# keycloak: "Failed to read artifact descriptor" error

Tags: java, maven, keycloak

I'm using the Java-based Keycloak server and attempting to run the demo examples.  I'm a bit of a Java hack, so please pardon my naiveté.

I'm getting the error shown below -- any help debugging and solving would be appreciated.

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-7) Uncaught server error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.keycloak:photoz-authz-policy:jar:3.4.3.Final
```

I had some trouble getting M2_HOME set so that keycloak could locate artifacts.  I seem to be past that problem and now, but I'm not sure where to go with the above error.  I've included some system info below.  And if someone's really eager, the [dockerfile is available](https://github.com/hellobrett/-keycloak-examples).

I'm running v3.5.3 of maven:

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.5.3 (3383c37e1f9e9b3bc3df5050c29c8aff9f295297; 2018-02-24T19:49:05Z)
Maven home: /usr/local/apache-maven
Java version: 1.8.0_151, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-1.b12.el7_4.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I ran `mvn -U clean install` in the project directory, and the artifacts appear to be built correctly:

```
[jboss@09fea4c663e0 ~]$ ll .m2/repository/org/keycloak/photoz-authz-policy/3.4.3.Final/
total 44
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 5169 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss   32 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final.jar.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss   40 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss  773 Jan  4 09:24 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final.pom
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss   32 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final.pom.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss   40 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final.pom.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss 3859 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final-sources.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss   32 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final-sources.jar.md5
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss   40 Mar 28 17:16 photoz-authz-policy-3.4.3.Final-sources.jar.sha1
-rw-r--r-- 1 jboss jboss  262 Mar 28 17:16 _remote.repositories
```

And finally, here's the metadata associated with the artifact:

```
[jboss@09fea4c663e0 ~]$ cat .m2/repository/org/keycloak/photoz-authz-policy/maven-metadata-local.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<metadata>
  <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
  <artifactId>photoz-authz-policy</artifactId>
  <versioning>
    <release>3.4.3.Final</release>
    <versions>
      <version>3.4.3.Final</version>
    </versions>
    <lastUpdated>20180328171633</lastUpdated>
  </versioning>
</metadata>
```

Any insight?

Comment: Which demo example? How you running? Is your keycloak up and running? How you deploy demo example ? What demo example exactly doing ?When this error came,war deployment time or war deployed and server started successfully and when try to run the web-app?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi,  thanks for taking a look.  I'll update this question in a bit -- things are better as of last night.  The full stack trace was illuminating  -- duh.  I needed to run mvn clean install from the parent directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the examples to run by copying the project files to the server and compiling on the server.  That seems strange to me -- a fat WAR seems like it would make more sense.  That is, I wouldn't expect to have to have supporting libraries compiled on a the server, but that strategy allowed me to move on.  Here are the commands I ran on my wildfly server (Dockerfile commands):

```
# Build and install keycloak example libraries
WORKDIR /opt/jboss
USER jboss
COPY --chown=jboss:jboss _srv/keycloak-demo-3.4.3.Final ./_srv/keycloak-demo-3.4.3.Final
WORKDIR _srv/keycloak-demo-3.4.3.Final/examples
RUN mvn -U clean install
WORKDIR /opt/jboss
```